# Sending JSON to server, using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to send simple data to theservre, and I need a "rough and ready" way to do this.

This is what I have so far:

```
var emails = ['a@123.com', 'b@123.com', 'c@123.com'];

var ruff_json = "{ 'emails': [";
for (i in emails)
    ruff_json += ((i == 0) ? '' : ', ') + '\''+emails[i]+'\'';

ruff_json += '] }';

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '1.php',
    data: ruff_json,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function(result){
        //do something
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Using Firebug, I can see that the data is POSTed to the server - however, at the server, there is no data ($_POST is empty) - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use a JSON encoding library instead of rolling your own. Try: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We post all of our data with json.

```
var myobj = { this: 'that' };
$.ajax({
  url: "my.php",
  data: JSON.stringify(myobj),
  processData: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success:function(a) { },
  error:function() {}
});
```

then in php we do

```
<?php
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
  // Access your $json['this']
  // then when you are done
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  print json_encode(array(
    "passed" => "back"
  ));
?>
```

This way we don't even mess with the post variables, and in general, its faster than having jQuery process them.

Comment: In the end it was a combination of using jSONLint, jquery-json and directly reading from php://input that helped me solve this problem. My biggest shock was to find that even though the data was being POSTed as JSON, it did not appear in $_POST. I only selected this answer because it had most of the valid points, and Jeremy took the time to provide some code to demonstrate what he meant.

Comment: This is because posted json is not the format php is expecting to populate $_POST.  Its more akin to post a file, although, it won't appear in $_FILES

Answer (score 2):

Your data field should contain an object with key-value pairs, because it gets encoded as POST key-values pairs.

```
data = {my_json: encoded_string};
```

Then on the PHP side you can access the data as:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['my_json']);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP populates `$_POST` by parsing the data received. However, it only knows form-encoded data, JSON data cannot be parsed automatically. So `$_POST` will be useless in this case. You need to [get the raw post data](http://php.net/%24HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) and parse it with `json_decode`.